# ASP ServerVariables logon user

Tags: asp.net, insert, insert-into

In my code behind, I have this

```
{
    Label2.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]"; 
}
```

to identify the username in domain. So far so good. It works properly in IIS.

However, I would like to store the username into a database. How can I do that?

The idea is to record the person who answer to this:

```
string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO worker(Business,Business2,Mobile) VALUES (@Business,@Business2,@Mobile)";
using (Conn)
{
    Conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertCmd, Conn);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business", business.Text);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business2", business2.Text);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", mobile.Text);
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Label1.Text = "Saved Successfull!";
    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

I have the answer inserted into the database, but how can I save the person who answer? Can I save the label into the database table? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `username` field to your table and add another parameter:

```
string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO worker(Business,Business2,Mobile,username) VALUES (@Business,@Business2,@Mobile,@username)"; 

using (Conn) { 
  Conn.Open(); 
  OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertCmd, Conn); 
  myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business", business.Text); 
  myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business2", business2.Text); 
  myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", mobile.Text); 
  myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name); 
  myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

  Label1.Text = "Saved Successfull!"; 
  Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green; 

}
```

Comment: i add it but give me error.
"OleDbException was unhandled by user code. Syntax error in INSERT INTO"

Comment: my bad! the problem its the database ..- (noob)

thanks! it works

Comment: you help one time @Peter Hahndorf maybe you could help me once again. How can i read the database and if the username exist show the row from that specific username and if not insert into